# Jquery "this" in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm having some problems with IE in the code below:

```
var energia = $(".energia").html().replace("%", "");
var guias = $(".guias").html().replace("%", "");
var pavim = $(".pavim").html().replace("%", "");
var rede_a = $(".rede_agua").html().replace("%", "");
var rede_d = $(".rede_drena").html().replace("%", "");
var total = $(".total").html().replace("%", "");

$('div.progresso').css({ backgroundPosition: "0px 85px" });
$('div.progresso').bind('mouseover', function() {
    var fclass = $(this).attr("class");
    switch (fclass) {
        case (fclass = "progresso energia"):
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundPosition: "(0px " + energia + "px)" }, { duration: 500 });
            break;
        case (fclass = "progresso guias"):
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundPosition: "(0px " + guias + "px)" }, { duration: 500 });
            break;
        case (fclass = "progresso pavim"):
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundPosition: "(0px " + pavim + "px)" }, { duration: 500 });
            break;
        case (fclass = "progresso rede_agua"):
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundPosition: "(0px " + rede_a + "px)" }, { duration: 500 });
            break;
        case (fclass = "progresso rede_drena"):
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundPosition: "(0px " + rede_d + "px)" }, { duration: 500 });
            break;
        default:
            fclass = null;
            break;
    }
});
```

And here the HTML:

```
<div class="ball ball_energia grande bold"><div class="progresso energia">10%</div></div>
    <div class="ball ball_guias grande bold"><div class="progresso guias">10%</div></div>
    <div class="ball ball_pavim grande bold"><div class="progresso pavim">30%</div></div>
    <div class="ball ball_rede_agua grande bold"><div class="progresso rede_agua">90%</div></div>
    <div class="ball ball_rede_drena grande bold"><div class="progresso rede_drena">80%</div></div>
    <div class="ball_maior grande2 bold"><div class="progresso_maior total">50%</div></div>
```

The function must catch each number in its respective div and treat itself executing the function that I call, that must separate each div with its number and change the position of the background separately for them.

In chrome and firefox, the function works nicely, but in IE, it do not work and it function as a single number.. where am i wrong?

Comment: Your case statements are mal-formed, ex. case (fclass = "progresso energia"): should be case "progresso energia":

Comment: Thats it! Thanks ron tornambe, you solve the mistake.. jrummell, I cannot see any error in IE :/ Thank you all!

Comment: Oh, so it was that after all. :) @FabioSampaio If you are using IE>7, then F12 gives you console. You can see errors there.

Comment: @freakish in IE all bad things can happen ^^

Comment: @freakish The expression is set in the switch declaration so you would not set the expression with the label.  In addition, just because something works, doesn't mean its the right way to do it.

Comment: @RobB I would *love* to see what you call the *right way to do it*...This is such an ambiguous and generalized statement, as with JavaScript/jQuery, there's almost *never* one right way to do something.

Comment: Yes, there is a "wrong" way to do it. There are several "right" ways, too, but far more wrongs than rights. Here, for example, the use of the entire class string as the value to switch against is fragile -- one `addClass` and it's done for. The switch itself contains duplicated code: DRY. The switch itself isn't necessary. See? Wrong way :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for the HTML5 data attribute. jQuery has shimmed support for these values, so you're good on older user agents too.

What you end up with is much cleaner code:

**HTML markup**

```
<div class="ball ball_energia grande bold">
    <div data-position="energia" data-position-value="10%" class="progresso">
        10%
    </div>
</div>
```

Note the `data-position-value` attribute I've put on the element. I also included a `data-postition` attribute, but we won't use that in the example because now, the `switch` isn't needed at all.

**Javascript**

```
$('div.progresso').bind('mouseover', function() {
    var value= $(this).data("position-value");
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundPosition: "(0px " + value + "px)" }, { duration: 500 });

    // for testing, output the value being used
    $('#display').html(value);
});
```

In this code block, we're pulling the desired value right off the element using the `data()` method. We can then use a generic line of script to change the background to the desired position.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Mrra3/

**Documentation**

- Global attributes (see section on `data-`) on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Global_attributes
- `element.dataset` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dataset
- jQuery `data` - http://api.jquery.com/data/